# Slow pip Raspberry PI 1

Tags: raspbian, pip

i have a issue with slow `pip` on Raspberry PI 1 on fresh install Raspbian Stretch.

When i ran `pip freeze` it take a long time.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ time pip freeze > /dev/null

real    0m43.337s
user    0m39.600s
sys     0m1.170s
```

I tried reinstall 2 times and still same. Have someone idea where can be problem?

Comment: Same problem on the Pi2 and 3: On a RPI3, a simple `pip --version` took about 6 seconds to complete. Using Pi3, even nearly 9 seconds. This seems also affecting packages installed by pip like `docker-compose`. Here, a simple `docker-compose --version` takes about 7 seconds. Did you find any solution on this issue? Other tools like `docker` itself are quite fast (100ms)

Comment: @Lion no, i didn't found any solution :/ i'm quite upset because pip is unusable with this 'speed'